# Free Code Camp: Twitch TV Project. How to implement online, offline, all toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really stuck at this stage. I do not know how to implement this feature. What i thought was to hide the whole divs which contain the appropriate statuses (online, offline, all). I know that there are a lot intelligent ways to do it. However, because i'm beginner i cannot get it done. Please experienced programmers help me out or please give me your valuable tips.

Code which kind of "responsible" this feature.

```
$('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
var spanStatus = document.querySelector("span");
var status = $('input[name=status]:checked', '#myForm').val();

for (var i=0; i<spanStatus.length; i++) {
  if (status=="offline") {

    //$("div").not("#status-toggle").hide();
    jQuery('span').parent().parent().hide();

  }
   console.log(spanStatus);

}
```

I know my code it total mess. Nevertheless this is link to my [pen](https://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/EyjQQQ). Do not be scared please i promise to improve my coding every day.

Comment: you are trying to select "span", I can't see it anywhere on your html

Comment: "span" is created dynamically in javaScript part: <span>'+status+'</span>